# Merging specific parts of code(functions, controllers) for different platforms in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

The problem in my case is how to merge for example a specific function that is different for each platform, for example IOS and Android platforms.

I found that cordova can merge files, but not functions. I saw that cordova has **merges/android** and **merges/ios** folders. But the problem is that cordova merge by filename and not by function. What i mean is that in one .js file i can have 30 functions and only 2 of them is different for each platform, how to merge only functions.
There is an another way to check the platform in my code and continue with the logic, but that's not what i want...

Comment: You have to put all the different functions on the merges/platform folder on the same file, there is no other way.

Comment: Yes i saw that there is no other way in cordova. For example in IBM Worklight platform, you can put only the functions in other file and the platform knows which function to be executed for specific platform...